# Screenshot of current window

Tags: gnome, graphics, screenshot

When I select to "Grab the current window" using the Screenshot app which comes with Ubuntu, the image is b0rked.

[image]

The same window captured with "Select area to grab" looks normal:

[image]

I am using gnome 3 + ubuntu 13.04, on an ASUS zenbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try Shutter. It's the screenshot tool I personally use and I find it better and handy compared to other screenshot tools.

To install,

```
sudo aptitude install shutter
```

Change aptitude to apt-get if you're not an aptitude user.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried, and I couldn't duplicate.  It could have something to do with your video driver. Try

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once that is done try aging to grab the image, and see if the problem goes away.

Screenshot is good, but I would suggest that you use Shutter.  Shutter gives you m ore control over captured images, among other thing, like adding a text box, arrow, etc.  To install Shutter, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```