# Window screenshot with Unity Global Menu enabled

Tags: unity, screenshot, globalmenu

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, it only shoots when I release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, so it gets a screenshot of the Global Menu.

How do I get the screenshot of the window without disabling Global Menu?

Comment: Try Shutter.  Look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298491/screenshot-of-current-window/298516#298516).

Comment: It solves my problem, you may answer the question.

Comment: I can't add the answer here, it then would be a duplicate.  I'm glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Shutter would work (as Mitch mentioned in the comments above), but you can also just use the default screenshot program.

One option is to hold down <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>, then let go of <kbd>shift</kbd> (but still hold <kbd>alt</kbd>) and finally hit <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>. Holding and letting go of <kbd>shift</kbd> prevents the menu or HUD from being invoked.

You can also just set a delay. Type `screenshot` into the Dash, then select `Grab the current window` with a time delay of your choice. One set, the settings will disappear and you can select the window you want an image of.